# Python 3 tkinter water alarm DID NOT GO in the IF LOOP

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to learning python gui with programming some mini projects. so now i tried to program a water alarm but the problem is that at one part my program did not go in the if loop. here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

#Eingabefeld=EF / Button= BN/ Label= LB

import csv
import datetime
import os
import sys
import csv 
import time
import webbrowser
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


path= '\\Users\YIF5WI\water alert\wateralarm'
filename= 'godhelpme.csv'
global fullpath
fullpath= os.path.join(path,filename)

class Waterentry:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master    

        master.title('Water controller')
        master.configure(bg='light blue')

        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()         
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight() 
        x = ws - 350
        y = hs - 300
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (350, 300, x, y))

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.configure(bg='light blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        self.LB_txt= Label(self.frame,bg='light blue', text='Choose how much you drink or \n Write the amount of water in ml!!!')
        self.LB_txt.pack(side=TOP)

        self.txtDisplay = Entry(self.frame,bd= 20, insertwidth=1, font= 30)
        self.txtDisplay.pack(side= TOP)
        self.txtDisplay.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.checkifdigit)

        self.frame2=Frame(master)
        self.frame2.configure(bg='light blue')
        self.frame2.pack(side = TOP)
        self.BN_txtOk= Button(self.frame2,text ='OK',bg = 'green',fg='white', padx=38, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : self.txtOk(self.txtDisplay))
        self.BN_txtOk.grid(row=0, column= 0)


        self.LB_info= Label(self.frame2,bg='light blue', text='1 Suppenloffel=10ml/ Ein Schluck  min = 20ml,max=40ml')
        self.LB_info.grid(row=1)

        self.frame3= Frame(master)
        self.frame3.configure(bg='light blue')
        self.frame3.pack(side=TOP)
        self.BN_water= Button(self.frame3, text ='100ml',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : self.addNumber('100ml'))
        self.BN_water.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.BN_water1= Button(self.frame3, text ='200ml',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : self.addNumber('200ml'))
        self.BN_water1.pack(side = LEFT)        
        self.BN_water2= Button(self.frame3, text ='300ml',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : self.addNumber('300ml'))
        self.BN_water2.pack(side = LEFT)        
        self.BN_water3= Button(self.frame3, text ='0,5L',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : self.addNumber('500ml'))
        self.BN_water3.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.BN_water4= Button(self.frame3, text ='1L',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : self.addNumber('1000ml'))
        self.BN_water4.pack(side = LEFT)

    def checkifdigit(self, EN_number):
        if not self.txtDisplay.get().isdigit():
            txt = self.txtDisplay.get()[:-1]
            self.txtDisplay.delete(0, END)
            self.txtDisplay.insert(0, txt)
        else:
            self.txtDisplay.get()


    def txtOk(self,EN_number):
        EN_number = self.txtDisplay.get()    
        print(EN_number)

        with open(fullpath,'a',) as f:  
            writer = csv.writer(f)     
            ohne_ml=re.sub(r'\D', '',EN_number)  
            writer.writerow(ohne_ml.split(','))                
        return

    def addNumber(self,BN_number):         
        print(BN_number)        
        with open(fullpath,'a') as f:
            writer1=csv.writer(f)
            new= re.sub(r'\D', '',BN_number)
            writer1.writerow(new.split(','))                    
        return  

def entry():
    root1= Tk()
    waterentry= Waterentry(root1)

    root1.mainloop()
```

here at the main function i have the problem

```
def opentkformessage():   
    root=Tk()
    root.withdraw()


def checkentry():
    try:
        with open('godhelpme.csv') as input, open('godhelpme1.csv', 'w') as output:
            non_blank = (line for line in input if line.strip())
            output.writelines(non_blank)

        with open("godhelpme1.csv") as fin:
            total = 0
            for row in csv.reader(fin):
                total += int(row[0])
                global total_liter
                total_liter= total * 0.001
        print(total_liter)
    except:
        opentkformessage()
        messagebox.showinfo('Water drink program','You must add your drunked water')
        entry()


def main():

    checkentry()
    opentkformessage()   
    global total_liter

    if (total_liter < 0.5):      
        messagebox.showinfo('WARNING','Drunked water:' +str(total_liter)+' L\nGOOO and take  minumum 0.2Liter WATER!!!\n You have 60 seconds!!')
        entry()  
        #time.sleep(10)
        **# HERE IS MY PROBLEM AFTER I CALL THE ENTRY() FUNCTION 
        # the if total_liter<0.2 will passed**
        checkentry()
        time.sleep(5)
        if (total_liter < 0.2):
            count = 0
            while count <5:
                os.system('water.jpg')
                time.sleep(5)
                webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRYMOIn45uE')
                time.sleep(15)
                os.system('water.png')
                time.sleep(5)
                os.system('water.jpg')
                time.sleep(5)
                count +=1
            entry()    

        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('INFO','Good you reach 0.5Liter')


    elif(0.501 < total_liter < 1.0):
        messagebox.showinfo('INFO', 'Drunked water:' +str(total_liter)+' L\nTry to drink approximately 0.3 liter\nfor the next hour' )
        entry() 

    elif(1.01 < total_liter < 2.0):
        messagebox.showinfo('INFO', 'Drunked water:' +str(total_liter)+' L\n Try to reach min water level.\n' )
        entry() 

    #elif (2.01 < total_liter):
        #messagebox.showinfo('INFO','Good!\n You reach the minumum water level.\nYou totally drink:'+str(total_liter)+' L')
        #entry()
    elif (2.1 < total_liter ): 
        messagebox.showinfo('INFO','Good!\n You reach the minumum water level.\nYou totally drink:'+str(total_liter)+' L\n Now your saved drunked water will cleaned')
        os.remove('godhelpme.csv')

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Something is wrong but, i don t now what:-)')

    #threading.Timer(10.0, main).start()
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

after the keyinterrupt i get:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File"finish.py", line 181, in<module>
 main()
File"finish.py", line 138,in main
 entry()
File"finish.py", line 103,in entry
 root1.mainloop()
```

Comment: did it go to the else bracket or just not run at all?

Comment: no i didnt go to the else bracket . for example if the total_liter =1.4 
then the elif(1.01 < total_liter < 2.0): loop will executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting a tkinter mainloop. The mainloop is an infinite loop that controls everything about tkinter- once you enter, you're in the event loop and further code doesn't execute unless you give input that's bound to run code or scheduled callbacks in the event loop. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop) is a good reference on the matter.

The main point is that you have to mentally substitute any tkinter `.mainloop()` as though it were `while True: do tkinter_updates`. The best way to run things is to register a majority of your `main()` function as its own function. You can then call `root.after(1000, main)` to schedule the function to run after the mainloop starts up.

---

A word of warning: your code can start multiple mainloops. This is a bad thing, as they *will* be improperly scoped (one mainloop can't see the data of its parent mainloop) and can cause myriad bugs and leak memory (since you're allocating the stuff for a new mainloop, but the old stuff is still accessible; you're using recursion). Make sure your code cannot start more than one mainloop or you *will* have problems with it.

Also, never use `time.sleep()` with tkinter; while Python is sleeping, tkinter cannot update or receive input. Use `root.after()` to schedule things to happen in the future- it's roughly as consistent as `time.sleep()`, doesn't freeze the whole GUI, and works better in general with tkinter.

Comment: thank you for the good information with the root.after method. i will not use time.sleep but i didn´t understand why my program doesnt go in the loop.-->if (total_liter < 0.2):

Comment: @kpl33 because it can't. It's stuck in the tkinter mainloop- when you execute `root.mainloop`, it's in a `while true` loop. It only exits this loop when all of tkinter is finished- i.e. when there are no more windows to draw/update/track (or when you manage to detach the windows from the interpreter, which is a problem- don't try to do that, it'll break things).

Comment: hmm ok i understand  i ask that again because it works if i have seperata programs . When in one is the gui and on the other is my main and if i call the gui with the command subprocess.Popen() it works. I just thought its looking better if i have this in one program.